# Addresses in assembly code and "lea"

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

If I say:

```
lea (%eax,%eax,2), %edx
```

I've been taught that it essentially means:

```
edx = eax + eax * 2
```

How does the format to this work?

And I guess this leads into the second question. If I have something like this:

```
add -0x4(%esi, %ebx, 4), %eax
```

I understand that the first operand is added to the second operand and then stored in the second operand, but again, what I don't understand is the first operand's notation. Another example would be if I had:

```
cmp %eax, (%esi, %ebx, 4)
```

..., does this mean that the value at %eax is being compared with the value of:

```
esi + ebx * 4
```

...? I tried searching a lot of this stuff but I guess I wasn't using the correct words to find a meaningful answer so I decided to post here.

Comment: Your lines are "AT&T assembler syntax", as used by the Gnu assembler (GAS). There are some manuals online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating values with `lea` is a reminiscent where this operation was either faster (as it was calculated by the circuitry doing address calculation) or smaller in code size. Note that with just one operation you're able to do an add and a multiplication in just one step. Current processors may be faster in doing it instead an `add` followed by a `mul`, but it is not clear given speculative execution, arithmetic unit replication, etc.

As for the following instructions, whenever you see the parentheses mean you're dereferencing that address, so:

```
add -0x4(%esi, %ebx, 4), %eax
```

means put in `%eax` what it is in the address given by `-4 + esi + ebx*4`, so it implies accessing to that position in memory and assigning what's stored there to `%eax`.

Comment: I doubt that the scale factor was ever implemented as a multiply, it was probably just a left shift.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was confused on the "formula" when dereferencing.

Comment: You've got a typo in there: it's `-4`, not `+4`.

Comment: @Gabriel yes, you're right. It is a shift. My assembler is rusty, but that's the idea. Joining two operations in one if the compiler (or you) can manage to arrange the computations that way. kay: Oops, you're right. It was edited by Bo Persson.